# sort python list of dictionaires based on value of 2 keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries that I would like to sort based on the value of a key 'index' as long as another key called 'verifier' is equal to 1. Both keys are present in all dictionaries on the list

I can sort the list with the code below... but not sure how to add another condition (I would prefer not to filter the list before as I would need all dictionaries, even the ones which do not match the key 'verifier' = 1 condition)

```
product_list = sorted(product_list, key=lambda k: k['index'])
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

my dictionary is like the one below...

```
product_list=[{'index':1,'key1':'xxx','key2':'xxx','verifier':0},{'index':2,'key1':'xxx','key2':'xxx','verifier':1},{'index':3,'key1':'xxx','key2':'xxx','verifier':0},{'index':4,'key1':'xxx','key2':'xxx','verifier':1}]
```

And I would like to return this:

```
product_list=[{'index':2,'key1':'xxx','key2':'xxx','verifier':1},{'index':4,'key1':'xxx','key2':'xxx','verifier':1},{'index':1,'key1':'xxx','key2':'xxx','verifier':0},{'index':3,'key1':'xxx','key2':'xxx','verifier':0}]
```

The list sorted by key verifier first and then by key index

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Where should items with `'verifier' != 1` be sorted? Beginning or end?

Comment: It might be helpful to provide an actual example of the data before and after sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key function can return a tuple of sort keys; when the first value in the tuple is equal for two values, the second item in the tuple is compared, etc.:

```
product_list = sorted(product_list, key=lambda k: (k['verifier'] == 1, k['index']))
```

This returns a `(boolean, k['index'])` tuple, grouping all values with `k['verifier']` being equal to 1 or not. Items with `k['verifier'] != 1` are sorted at the start as `False` is sorted before `True`. Use `k['verifier'] != 1` if you want to invert that order.

Or you could return `None` for items where `k['verifier'] != 1`:

```
product_list = sorted(product_list, key=lambda k: k['index'] if k['verifier'] == 1 else None)
```

and this will again group your items into those that have `verifier` set to `1` and those that are not, but won't further sort the items `k['verifier'] != 1`. In Python 2, `None` is always sorted first, so all items with `k['verifier'] != 1` will be grouped at the front of the list. Use `float('inf')` instead of `None` if the should come last instead, provided all `k['index']` values are numeric.

This is most easily illustrated with a small demo set of data:

```
>>> product_list = [{'index': 12, 'verifier': 1}, {'index': 3, 'verifier': 0}, {'index': 9, 'verifier': 1}, {'index': 2, 'verifier': 0}]
>>> sorted(product_list, key=lambda k: (k['verifier'] == 1, k['index']))
[{'index': 2, 'verifier': 0}, {'index': 3, 'verifier': 0}, {'index': 9, 'verifier': 1}, {'index': 12, 'verifier': 1}]
>>> sorted(product_list, key=lambda k: k['index'] if k['verifier'] == 1 else None)
[{'index': 3, 'verifier': 0}, {'index': 2, 'verifier': 0}, {'index': 9, 'verifier': 1}, {'index': 12, 'verifier': 1}]
```

The difference between the two sorts is that the first two items are left in original list order in the `else None` sort. Grouping the `k['verifier'] != 1` items last:

```
>>> sorted(product_list, key=lambda k: (k['verifier'] != 1, k['index']))
[{'index': 9, 'verifier': 1}, {'index': 12, 'verifier': 1}, {'index': 2, 'verifier': 0}, {'index': 3, 'verifier': 0}]
>>> sorted(product_list, key=lambda k: k['index'] if k['verifier'] == 1 else float('inf'))
[{'index': 9, 'verifier': 1}, {'index': 12, 'verifier': 1}, {'index': 3, 'verifier': 0}, {'index': 2, 'verifier': 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martjin... I tried both options but It does not seem to work... the dictionaries are still sorted by key index in first place... I will edit the post to clarify it a bit more...

Comment: @Martjin: Your code is fine, the mistake is somewhere else in my code... do you know if its possible that when I pass this dictionary list from one function to another it might change the list order?

Comment: I illustrated the different options; do you understand what the differences are here? One option sorts both groups, the other leaves the non-verified items in original order but grouped to one side.

Comment: You can sort in-place instead? Use `list.sort()` instead of `sorted()`.

Comment: Thanks Martjin, I understood the examples, very clear... I was looking for the 1st option you described (sort first key 1 then key 2). I will try with list.sort... thanks again!!!